# Как удалить виджет в tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
w = Tk()
w.title('@')
w.geometry('650x500')
b = Button(w)
b.grid()
w.mainloop()
```

Как удалить виджет b?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть несколько способов
Вот они:

```
b.grid_forget() - спрячет виджет
b.grid_remove() - удалит виджет
```

Answer (score 3):

Для полного удаления виджета можно использовать метод `destroy`, пример:

```
def on_press():
    b.destroy()

b = Button(w, command=on_press)
```

После нажатия кнопка удалится полностью (т.е. с ней больше нельзя будет ничего сделать: например, при попытке разместить ее повторно будет ошибка).

Если виджет нужно временно удалить из окна с возможностью потом вернуть, то используйте следующие методы:

- Методы `.grid_forget`, `.pack_forget` (он же  просто `.forget`), `.place_forget` удаляют виджет из окна, но виджет продолжает сущестовать, его можно снова разместить в окне.
- Метод `.grid_remove` позволяет скрыть виджет, и потом вернуть его обратно с теми же параметрами и в то же место (в ту же строку и колонку сетки) просто вызовом `.grid()` без параметров.

Answer (score -1):

```
b.grid_remove()
b.grid_forget()
b.pack_forget()
```

Comment: Что этот ответ добавляет к уже имеющимся ответам?