# Можно ли создать виджет в уже открытом окне Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Я имею в виду не закрыть и открыть окно а именно добавить или удалить виджет в открытом окне. Я видел темы с `root.update()` но так и не разобрался как это работает.

Comment: Создать - так же как обычно создаете. Удалить - см.:  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1219484/1365 . `root.update()` вообще с этим никак не связано.

Answer (score 0):

Можно. А в чём, собственно, проблема? Вот простейший пример, где по нажатию кнопки добавляются `Label`:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
import time

def btn_press():
    texts = ["Ой!", "Кнопку нажали", "Больно же!", "Хватит в меня тыкать!", "И не надоело тебе?", "А вот и не нажмусь!"]
    wd = tk.Label(frm, text="ЖДИТЕ ....")
    wd.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
    wnd.update_idletasks()   # или просто update()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    wd["text"] = random.choice(texts)
    

wnd = tk.Tk()

wnd.title("Динамическое добавление виджетов")
wnd.geometry('300x520')

frm = tk.Frame(wnd)
frm.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

lbl = tk.Label(frm, text="Привет")
lbl.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)

btn = tk.Button(wnd, foreground="yellow", background="#aa2222", text="Нажми на меня", command=btn_press)
btn.pack(fill=tk.X)

wnd.mainloop()
```

Если не использовать `update()` (или его более простой вариант `update_idletasks()`, то на экране ничего не обновится до тех пор пока функция не завершится и программа не вернётся в свой mainloop. Соответственно, не будет видна промежуточная надпись "ЖДИТЕ", и даже кнопка не отожмётся. Если функции (обработчики событий) завершаются быстро, то никаких `update()` вызывать даже не нужно. По правильному, программа должна быть написана так, чтобы вызов `update()` нигде не понадобился.

Если в программе выше убрать `time.sleep(0.5)`, то и `wnd.update_idletasks()` не нужен.